# Create empty string names in strings.xml file from pattern (out of runtime)

Tags: android

How to create empty string names in strings.xml:

```
<string name="pyt11"></string>
<string name="obraz11"></string>
<string name="odp1_11"></string>
<string name="odp2_11"></string>
etc.
```

with pattern wroted below:

```
for(int n=1; n<5; n++) {
    for (int i=1; i<100; i++) {
String pyt = "pyt"+i+n;
String obraz = "obraz"+i+n;
String odp1 = "odp1_"+i+n;
String odp2 = "odp2_"+i+n;
String odp3 = "odp3_"+i+n;
String odp4 = "odp4_"+i+n;
String odp5 = "odp5_"+i+n;
String podp = "podp"+i+n;
String exp = "exp"+i+n
}
}
```

Comment: huh? what you mean?

Comment: I mean it takes a lot of time to set hundreds string names in strings.xml manually. I want to set it automatically with above pattern.